# How to fire an Event via Fuel SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, java, fuel-sdk

I want to implement this procedure via Java fuelsdk

https://code.exacttarget.com/marketing-automation/journey-builder/events/how-to-fire-an-event

```
    ETClient client = new ETClient();
    ETRestConnection restConnection = client.getRESTConnection();

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + client.getAccessToken());
    jsonObject.addProperty("EventDefinitionKey", "XXXXXX-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx");

    //Not able to create TreeMap
    //"Data": {
    //      "accountNumber":"123456",
    //      "patronName":"John Smith" }
    }

    String result = restConnection.post("/interaction-experimental/v1/events", jsonObject);
    System.out.println("Result:::" + result);
```

**UPDATED**

Finally, I figured out how to do that, but after successfull execution, nothing happens.

```
2014-06-16T19:34:11.815+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: 201 Created 
2014-06-16T19:34:11.817+0200 main com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETRestConnection DEBUG: "{\r\n  \"eventInstanceId\": \"88607cad-9b8d-4391-bb88-ca9150d71d0d\"\r\n}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the payload you're sending, it appears you're missing the ContactKey or ContactID property. Knowing which one of these to use depends upon how the Interaction within Journey Builder is configured.

How has your Trigger been defined in the Trigger Administration View in Journey Builder? The preferred method is to use Contact Key as the mapping to the EventDataSource's Sendable Field.

It appears you're receiving an EventInstanceId as a response from the request. When you say "nothing happens", could you provide some more information please?
- Is the row added to the Event Data Source associated with the Trigger for the running Interaction?

Comment: Our DE wasn't created correclty,´EventInstanceId´ wasn't a PK. After creating the new DE correctly, everything works like a charm. Thank you

Comment: Today, it stopped working. What information do you need to tell us what is wrong?. Because, data has inserted correctly, EventInstanceId returned after API call. We are desperate.

Comment: When you say "stopped working", can you provide me with some more information please?

Comment: Thank you. How can I send you detailed information? I need to attach here traceback?